# iPhone OpenGL: Finding out the rotation of an object

Tags: iphone, opengl-es

I need to find the rotation of an object.  So I am rotating a cube on 2 axis and when a user clicks, I need to rotate the cube to the face they clicked on.  I looked at the ModelView matrix and converted the points from radian to degrees but the range goes from 0 to 180 (90 happens twice)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know a modelview matrix then you can find the quaternion representing your rotation unambiguously.

Here is a link with a formula to compute the quaternion from a rotation matrix http://www.euclideanspace.com/maths/geometry/rotations/conversions/matrixToQuaternion/index.htm

**EDIT:**

If you have 2 modelview matrices for your object and you want a smooth movement from one position to another you can still use quaternions!

Let you have 2 matrices `w1` `w2`. For each build a quaternion `q1` and `q2` using the existing formulas - it's simple. Make the animation like this:

on each animation step construct the current quaternion for object rotation:

```
allTransform = q2 - q1
currentTransform = q1 + t*allTransform
```

where `t` is from `[0, 1]`, allTransform is s quaternion
When you know the `currentTransform` quaternion build a model view matrix from it - just using a ready formula.

That will produce nice and smooth animation.

Comment: Not sure how to use this, I just need to find the degrees of x,y,z.  There must be a easy way to do this

Comment: It's not the best way to use angles because for each 3 angles (Euler's angles or Krilov's angles or some else) there is an ambiguity in determining one of the angle in some cases. Quaternion has no ambiguity and it's not hard at all to understand how it's work. You can read about quaternion in the internet but it means just a vector and an angle of rotation around this vector!

Comment: I am bloody stuck so I take your advise and investigate.  I now storing the matrix for each position but it just jumps to that, be nice if there was a function that animates between 2 matrix's